# Tanuki java service wrapper - jvm fails to restart and launches new jvm

Tags: java, jvm, tanuki

When Filter trigger matched for restart service, jvm(jvm1) is restarting but getting below message and it launches new jvm(jvm2)

> Shut-down execute...
>   JVM process exited with a code of 0, leaving the wrapper exit code set to 0.\n
>   JVM exited normally.
>   JVM was only running for 33 seconds leading to a failed restart count of 1.
>   Waiting 5 seconds before launching another JVM.
>   Launching a JVM…

Can any one share some input on this, whether is this expected behavior of wrapper or if jvm restart failed can be solved?